# Prefer 'www' subdomain with Node.js on Apache server

Tags: node.js, apache, .htaccess

I have a Node.js app on an Apache server (that is hosting other non-node.js sites). Here's the Apache setup to send all the traffic on www.mysite.com to Node on port 12001:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin contact@mysite.com
    ServerName  www.mysite.com
    ServerAlias mysite.com www.mysite.com

    ProxyRequests off

    <Proxy *>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>

    <Location />
        ProxyPass http://localhost:12001/
        ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:12001/
    </Location>

    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/mysite-error_log
    TransferLog /var/log/apache2/mysite-access_log
</VirtualHost>
```

And **I would like to force all people visiting mysite.com to be redirected to www.mysite.com**.

In Node, I can't check `req.headers.host` as it always equals `localhost:12001` and I'm not sure where I'm supposed to put any `.htaccess` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do it in your server config, no need for .htaccess. Add this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteRule (.+) http://www.example.com$1 [R=301,L]
```

(I had to use the standard `example.com` rather than your example domain as the system rejected that)

This says redirect anything that is **not** using host `www.example.com`, unless no host is specified (to avoid loops if serving a request with no host header), to `www.example.com`.

It is done this way so it can work with misspellings too like `ww.example.com` (a missing w) if you add the appropriate ServerAlias (perhaps *.example.com) and DNS entries (again a wildcard could be used) and also covers what you asked for, you don't have to do that.

It also preserves the rest of the URL, so:

```
http://example.com/testing
```

Will redirect to:

```
http://www.example.com/testing
```